# Link Navigation View Controller to a Nib using .xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xib

Is it possible to make a custom UINavigationController linked to a xib file?

I have a custom navigation controller. When I create a view on it programmatically, it appears on every view just like I want. But when I try to do it with a xib file, the view doesn't appear. It seems impossible to link the xib with all its views to my custom navigation controller.

I checked and in my xib file Identity Inspector, the File's Owner class is already linked to my custom navigation controller (I created the xib file by checking the checkbox when creating a new class for this NC).

EDIT: I also tried by subclassing initWithNibName: function but it's not working better. My xib doesn't show.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"SLVNavigationController" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating your custom navigation controller? You will need to use `initWithNibNam:nibBundle:` to reference the correct nib.

Comment: I already try this and it's not working better.